# make cufon in bold

Tags: css, fonts, cufon

I need to set a cufon text on hover in bold or font-weight:700;

the code is this

Cufon.replace('h1') ('h2') ('h3') ('h4') ('h5') ('h6') ('.navigation ul',{hover:true})('.slide-more') ('.heading1-slide') ('.heading2-slide') ('ul.navigation',{hover:true})('.more-button') ('.page-navigation',{hover:true}) ('.date') ('.month') ('.wp-pagenavi') ;

I need set .navigation ul and  ul.navigation in bold on hover.
How can do that?

Thanks

Comment: Please, *please*, carefully consider doing something else (change color, underline, something) to provide emphasis on hover. When you change weight to bold, it also changes the width of the text...which changes the position of the text underneath the hover. In some cases it can jump back and forth between regular and bold. This is really annoying from a user perspective. Personally, I black-list websites that do this; it is a terrible, awful UI practice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `{hover:true}`.
See example

```
Cufon.replace('h2, h3, h4', {hover: true});
```

I think you need to upload font(bold) to achieve bold style.
For instance
if you want to use Book Antiqua font for `regular,bold and itali`c then you need to upload actual font book Antiqua `(Regular, bold & italic)` and generate code.